# How to forbid slash '/' usage in entity attribute using jaxb and jaxrs

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

I have the following entity:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = EntityConstants.PARTNER)
public class FilePartner
{
    @XmlAttribute(name = EntityConstants.IDENTIFIER, required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(RestResourceIdJaxbAdapter.class)
    private String identifier;
    ...
}
```

Here is the jaxb adapter:

```
public class RestResourceIdJaxbAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String>
{
    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception
    {
        if (v != null && v.contains("/"))
        {
            // throw new ApiException(Status.BAD_REQUEST, RestErrorMessages.BAD_REQUEST_SUFFIX, "Identifier must not contain slashes");

            return v.replaceAll("/", "");
        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception
    {
        return v;
    }
}
```

I have a jaxrs service that accepts POST requests with body FilePartner:

```
@POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response createPartner(FilePartner partner,
                                  @Context UriInfo uriInfo,
                                  @HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT) String acceptHeader)
        throws ApiException
    {
        ...
    }
```

What I want to achieve is to forbid the usage of slashes '/' in the identifier attribute of the FilePartner entity.
Today I am doing this using some jaxb adapter which simply strips all slashes from the id when unmarshalling. 
Instead, what I would like is to return an appropriate BAD_REQUEST exception to the user.

I tried throwing exception in the unmarshal method of the jaxb adapter but seems that jaxrs is swallowing it and simply setting my identifier to null.
If we want to override this behavior I think I must create a new @Provider and register a special ValidationEventHandler in the unmarshaller that the javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader creates.
Unfortunately, this is impossible unless I define an explicit dependency to a JAX-RS implementation which I want to avoid.

Are there any other options to restrict the usage of slashes in the identifier attribute, without defining an explicit dependency to jersey/resteasy and without handling the restriction in the @POST method of the service?

Comment: Why don't you check for slash in post method itself (without adapting) and throw error

Comment: I wish I could do it declaratively. I stated that in the question.
The thing is - I have tens of similar rest services dealing with different but also very similar types of entities. 
I do not want to change all rest services POST methods but instead I'd prefer to annotate all entities.
One would think this is a common and very standard use case. I wonder why it is not easy to implement declaratively.

Comment: Ok @mdzh let me understand. I think we can solve it :). You have one entity shared across multiple rest calls, and want to prevent "/" only in one of the operation for same entity. Or you have many entities, and want to restrict only one entity to _not_ have a "/"

Comment: I have many entities, all having the "identifier" attribute. Using slashes in the identifier is not allowed for all entities.
On the other hand, I have tens of services all handling POST and PUT requests and they all accept different types of the aforementioned entities.

Comment: If you want declarative then jsr303 (validation api) might help. Did you check it out?

Answer (score 0):

To your rescue comes [`ReaderInterceptor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptor.html)

Don't do any special handling using `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`. Register a `ReaderInterceptor` with your Application class (if in jersey2) or in web.xml if earlier.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ReaderInterceptor;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ReaderInterceptorContext;
javax.ws.rs.ext.ReaderInterceptor

@Provider
public class ValidationInterceptor implements ReaderInterceptor {
    public ValidationInterceptor() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext readerInterceptorContext) throws IOException,
                                                                                           WebApplicationException {
        Object o = readerInterceptorContext.proceed();
        if (o instanceof FilePartner&& ((FilePartner) o).getIndentifier().contains("/")) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(400)
                                                      .entity("Identifier must not contain a slash")
                                                      .build());

        }
        return o;
    }
}
```

And register the interceptor to your `Application` in override of `public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()` method something like `classes.add(ValidationInterceptor.class);`

Hope that helps.